# sed substitute with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file `test123.txt` which contains one instance of a string like `clover-12345678.tmp`, where the prefix is always `clover-`, the suffix is always `.tmp`, but the number in between can be any 8 digit number.

I wish to substitute this string in the file with a different string, `butterfly`.

The regex for the string I wish to substitute is `clover-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\.tmp`.

My sed command for the substitution is:

```
sed -i -e "s/clover-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\.tmp/butterfly/g" test123.txt
```

However, this does not change anything in the `test123.txt` file, even though it contains one instance of `clover-12345678.tmp`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for characters classes and bracket expressions such as digits etc. and below these for regular expression extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

`\d` is just character `d`. Replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. You can also `[0-9]\{8\}{`